# Как сделать уведомления/оповещения  на JS?

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Есть задача сделать уведомления/оповещения о некоторых событиях в панели. Понятно, что нужно сделать js, который будет обращаться к php файлу, который будет проверять наличие обновлений, - это понятно сделать можно!

Но вот, допустим, у меня есть события по дате, например, напомнить к такому-то времени и дате, пришла эта дата, скрипты сработали и оповещение сработало. Но как его выводить, чтобы оно светилось в оповещениях до тех пор, пока не будет просмотрено.

Как такое сделать? Алгоритм, может, подскажите работы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти оповещения у вас хранятся в БД, я правильно понимаю?
Если так, то после запроса js скрипта на сервере он выводит это оповещение и сразу его удаляет, если оно не нужно, или, допустим, меняет его состояние (сделать отдельную колонку с состоянием оповещения), и всё, в чём проблемы?

Comment: имеете ввиду что-то типо статуса просмотра сообщения? если просмотрено то не показывать, если не просмотрено, то показывать.

Answer (score 2):

Писать в куки или в базу инфу о том, просмотрено или нет.